# node/pg/PSQL: Create Tables using Promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, promise

I am writing a simple Node/Express/React/Postgres application and I'm using the `pg` package to interface with my Postgres Server.

I require three tables, `table1`, `table2`, and `table3`. `table2` has a foreign key in `table1` and `table3` has a foreign key in `table 2`, so the order that I need to create the tables in is: `table1` then `table2` then `table3`.

I am attempting to use promises to enforce this order in my asynchronous table creation calls. I've generally followed [Brian Carlson's suggested Project Structure](https://node-postgres.com/guides/project-structure), but clearly I'm doing something wrong.

Here are the simplified, relevant files from my project:

`db.js:`

```js
const { Pool } = require('pg');

// Create pool connection to database
const pool = new Pool({
  user: XXXX,
  host: XXXX,
  database: XXXX,
  password: XXXX,
  port: XXXX
});

// Pool emitters
pool.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('Connected a client to the database');
});

pool.on('remove', () => {
  console.log('Disconnected a client from the database');
});

pool.on('error', (err, client) => {
  console.error('Unexpected error on idle client', err);
  process.exit(-1);
});

// This structure taken from Brian Carlson's pg API Documentation
// https://node-postgres.com/guides/project-structure
module.exports = {
  query: (text, params) => {
    console.log('Making a query!');
    return pool.query(text, params);
  }
};
```

`table_scripts.js:`

```js
const db = require('../db');

const Database_Scripts = {
  create_table_1: () => {
    const create_table_1_query = {
      text: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
        public.table_1
      (
        id smallserial,
        name text NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
      );`
    };
    return db.query(create_table_1_query);
  },

  create_table_2: () => {
    const create_table_2_query = {
      text: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
      public.table_2
    (
        id smallserial,
        table_1_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES public.table_1(id),
        name text NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    );`
    };
    return db.query(create_table_2_query);
  },

  create_projects_table: () => {
    const create_table_3_query = {
      text: `
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
          public.table_3
          (
           id smallserial,
           table_3_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES public.table_2(id),
           name text NOT NULL,
           PRIMARY KEY (id)
          );`
    };

    return db.query(create_table_3_query);
  }
};

module.exports = Database_Scripts;
```

`create_tables.js:`

```js
const Table_Scripts = require('./table_scripts');

Table_Scripts.create_table_1()
  .then(Table_Scripts.create_table_2())
  .then(Table_Scripts.create_table_3())
  .catch(error => console.log(error.stack));
```

`package.json:`

```js
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www",
    "create_tables": "node ./database/scripts/create_tables.js"
  }
}
```

When I run my `create_tables` script (`npm run-script create_tables`), I get the following (sanitized) errors:

```js
Connected a client to the database
Connected a client to the database
Connected a client to the database
Disconnected a client from the database
(node:13444) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: relation "public.table_1" does not exist
(node:13444) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a
catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:13444) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
Disconnected a client from the database
(node:13444) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: relation "public.table_2" does not exist
(node:13444) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a
catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
Disconnected a client from the database
```

I've been able to get this script to work converting the functions to async functions, however, I'd really like to understand what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you're concurrently creating the tables despite explicitly needing to do the opposite.

According to the [documentation](https://node-postgres.com/features/queries), `pool.query()` returns a promise if not provided a callback function as a third argument. You need to wait for each of your `db.query()` promises to be resolved. Thus it'll wait for the first table to be created, then create the second one and finally the third one.

I would recommend using the async/await syntax

```
async function createTables () {
    try {
        const create_table_1_query = {
            text: `yourQuery1`
        };
        // awaits for the first table to be created
        await db.query(create_table_1_query);

        const create_table_2_query = {
            text: `yourQuery2`
        };
        // awaits for the second table to be created
        await db.query(create_table_2_query);

        const create_table_3_query = {
            text: `yourQuery3`
        };
        // awaits for the third table to be created
        await db.query(create_table_3_query);
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e.stack);
    }
}

module.exports.createTables = createTables;
```

You can then call `await createTables();`